# why tkinter methods return a value when we don't expect them to

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote the following Tkinter code. When a user slides the scale widget, the font-size on the label is changed accordingly. I managed to do this but didn't understand why the function i wrote is returning a value when i didn't define it to do so. Is Tkinter returning something invisible implicitly ?

here is the code ...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()
master.geometry('650x350+50+200')

scale_1 = ttk.Scale(master, length=300, from_=10, to=60)
scale_1.pack(padx=20, pady=30, anchor='nw')

label_1 = ttk.Label(master, text='Hello World !!!', background='orange')
label_1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=True)


def changeFontSize():
    label_1.config(font=('candara', int(scale_1.get())))


scale_1.config(command=changeFontSize) # problem area

master.mainloop()
```

following was my workaround

```
def changeFontSize(x)
```

or

```
scale_1.config(command= lambda x: changeFontSize())
```

Comment: If you're getting an error like `TypeError: changeFontSize() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`, that doesn't mean your function is returning a value when it's not supposed to. That means it's being called with one argument, but it doesn't accept that many arguments. Both of your workarounds address that discrepancy.

Comment: The scale automatically passes the new value to the command. Your first "workaround" isn't a workaround, it's how it's designed to be used.